# How to reset Magento Form Validation?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise, forms, varien, prototype-js

I have a custom form in my magento store, and use varienform validation. Everything works fine. But requirement is, I need a clear button so that I can click that button to reset the form inputs including the validation error messages.

**the below image is my current form:**

[image]

after clicking **Clear** buton it should become like this:

[image]

How can I do this? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Form-Validator is defined here:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sendfriend/send.phtml:135
var productSendtofriendForm = new VarienForm('product_sendtofriend_form');
```

and the `VarienForm` has a `validator` and this `validator` has a `reset` method:

```
/js/prototype/validation.js:155
reset : function() {
    Form.getElements(this.form).each(Validation.reset);
},
```

Try this:

Add a clear button, give it suggestform_clear as id

```
<button type="button" title="Clear" class="button" id="suggestform_clear"><span>Clear</span></button>
```

and add this script below

```
var productSuggestForm = new VarienForm('form-suggestproduct');
$('suggestform_clear').observe('click', function(){
    productSuggestForm.validator.reset();
}.bind(productSuggestForm));
```

Comment: I added a clear button gave it suggestform_clear as id and added this script `$('suggestform_clear').observe('click', function(){
  productSuggestForm.validator.reset();
 });`
it doesn't work :(

Comment: are you sure, that this function is called? And that the name of the suggestForm VarienForm is correct?

Comment: sorry my bad! I failed to bind the form to the event.

I added a clear button gave it suggestform_clear as id and added this script `$('suggestform_clear').observe('click', function(){
  productSuggestForm.validator.reset();
 }.bind(productSuggestForm));`

it works like charm! Thank you so much :)